# JSRender/JSView repeat all template when I use for loop

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

I have an array with this format:

```
{[
{ title : "", artist : "" },
{ title : "", artist : "" },
{ title : "", artist : "" },
{ title : "", artist : "" }
]}
```

When I try print the data, I get the full template n times (Json data lenght). I have:

```
var list = new Array();
list.push({ title : **data**, artist : **data** });
var songsTemplate = $.templates("#topSongsTemplate");
var html = songsTemplate.render(list);
$("#topSongs").html(html);
```

I only want the for of my template repeats. But I get the full template all times repeated across my div. I am missing something?:

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="topSongsTemplate">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> <span data-i18n="search.top_tracks">Top 20 Tracks</span>
        <div class="separator hr-line-dashed m-t-xs"></div>
        <ol>
            {{for ~root }}
                <li>{{>title}} - <small>{{>artist}}</small></li>
            {{/for}}
        </ol>
    </div>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render without iteration you can write:

```
var html = songsTemplate.render(list, true);
```

See *Passing an array to render(), but without iteration.* in [this documentation topic](http://jsviews.com/#tmplrender@noiteration).

BTW then you can equally write `{{for}}` or `{{for #data}}` - though `{{for ~root}}` will also work.

Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28591715/1054484) to a similar question.

Comment: So great answer. So usefull!