# cannot run for loop twice in template

Tags: jsrender

Hi I am trying to run the for loop twice

```
<script id="row-property" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for }}
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-2">
            Cell {{:count}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <select id="cell_{{:count}}_size">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/for}}        

    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-2">
            <input id="row-apply" template="row-template" template-controls="{{for }} cell_{{:count}}_size, {{/for}}" clear-before-execute="true" template-output-selector=".focused.row" value="Apply" type="button" />
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

But all I get is

```
 <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-2">
            <input id="row-apply" template="row-template" template-controls=" cell_3_size, " clear-before-execute="true" template-output-selector=".focused.row" value="Apply" type="button" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

in the 2nd loop

Please help

Answer (score 0):

When I render the template, I need to "render without iteration" to me that means I enter the template with the array as appose to entering the template with each object and evaluating it.

```
var html = songsTemplate.render(list, true);
```

[JSRender/JSView repeat all template when I use for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429225/jsrender-jsview-repeat-all-template-when-i-use-for-loop)